# Missing last few lines of subprocess output when running without shell=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm running a simple Python 3.6 script via subprocess from another Python 3.6 script. I'm trapping SIGINT in the original process to pass it to the subprocess. This is just to test a module that will eventually be wrapping other things, but that's not too important.

When I start the subprocess *without* a shell and send SIGINT to stop it, the output is sometimes completely missing the traceback from the subprocess, other times it just contains the `Traceback (most recent call last):` line, and other times it contains the full traceback.

I'm using Popen, but I also verified that the same thing happens when using communicate() or with check_output & co.

However here's the kicker: if I set `shell=True` I always get the full traceback when sending SIGINT to the subprocess.

**Minimal Example**

`producer.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import signal
import time

for number in range(100):
    sys.stderr.write(str(number) + 'this is line ' + str(number) + '\n')
    time.sleep(0.01)
    sys.stderr.flush()
```

`consumer.py`

```py
import subprocess
import signal
import sys
import time

process = subprocess.Popen(['./producer.py'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    bufsize=1,
    #shell=True,
    encoding="latin-1",
    universal_newlines=True)

def stop_process(a,b):
    process.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

old_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, stop_process)
s, e =  process.communicate()
print(s)
print('-----')
print(e)
```

Try running `python3 consumer.py` and pressing CTRL+C at any point. If you try a few times, you should see the different behaviours I listed. Now try again after uncommenting `shell=True` in the consumer, and you should get the full traceback every time.

Anybody has any idea why this is? I'm suspecting python interpreter shenanigans, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl-C provides sigint to all processes involved and your relaying of it is getting the child hit with two (and a second while it is busy dying from the first causes it to bail without outputting what you expect from the first).  `shell=True` puts a shell between the parent and child.  The child still dies from its first sigint, and the shell ignores the double sigint and still waits for the child.